# PHP does not echo every result from query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT manufacturers_name FROM authors WHERE manufacturers_id IN 
(SELECT authors_id from authors_to_manufacturers WHERE manufacturers_id='776')
```

When I execute this in phpmyadmin I get 2 results, but when I try to echo them I get only the first one. Here's my code:

```
$link_query = xtc_db_query($thequeryfromabove);
$link = xtc_db_fetch_array($link_query);
foreach ($link as $v){
echo $v;
}
```

`var_dump($link)` gives me the following:

```
array (size=1)
  'manufacturers_name' => string 'Antoni, Michael' (length=15)
```

Comment: Show code for xtc_db_fetch_array(): does that function return all results, or only one?

Comment: xtc_db_fetch_array is ok, I've used it before. It's a substitute for mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: In that case, it only fetches a single result: You need to fetch eachresult in turn in a loop

Comment: Why is there a column called `manufacturers_name` (and `manufacturers_id`) in the `authors` table? This is very confused.

Answer (score 1):

As `xtc_db_fetch_array()` only fetches a single row from the resultset, you need to call it in a loop to fetch each row

```
while($link= xtc_db_fetch_array($link_query)) {
    echo $link['manufacturers_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch each row, and then loop around the fields.

Something like this:-

```
<?php
$link_query = xtc_db_query($thequeryfromabove);
while ($link = xtc_db_fetch_array($link_query))
{
    foreach ($link as $v)
    {
        echo $v;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To the posters before, they are looping inside a loop, which is going to hinder your results.

As you should be looping the query results, that is the only loop need.

May also be worth using fetch assoc, to be certain it's pulling an associative array
Example;

```
$link_query = xtc_db_query($thequeryfromabove);
while ($v = xtc_db_fetch_assoc(link_query))
{
    echo $v['manufacturers_name'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its an array you need to use key name as below

```
$link_query = xtc_db_query($thequeryfromabove);
  $link = xtc_db_fetch_array($link_query);
   foreach ($link as $v){
   echo $v['manufacturers_name'];
}
```

Comment: Depending on server config, fetch_array normally provides non-associated arrays (`$var[0]`, `$var[1]` etc) - using fetch_assoc has it always return associative array.

Comment: Yes you are right Luke, while($link= xtc_db_fetch_array($link_query)) {
    echo $link['manufacturers_name'];
} will work. thank